# 'unknown filesystem' grub rescue prompt; trying to wipe drive and boot 10.10 live

Tags: 10.10, grub2, live-usb

Im currently running Win7, and want to wipe the drive and install 10.10.

I have 10.10 loaded on a USB thumbdrive and it sees the device in BIOS but it only reaches a screen saying;

```
Unknown Filesystem
grub rescue>
```

Ive read several results from google and a couple here where people are trying to dual boot and i assume save the data on the drive, but i dont care about doing that, and would prefer to just wipe the drive and start fresh.

What steps can i take to get the drive to a point where i can load 10.10 live and get it installed?

Answer (score 1):

None of the common automated tools for creating an Ubuntu LiveUSB use grub2 (instead they use syslinux) so your immediate and likely only problem is that you're not actually booting from the Ubuntu LiveUSB but from a different drive (likely your internal hard drive).

Make sure that the USB drive is first in the boot order in your BIOS.